# Not able to add dependency to android project in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dependencies, native

Hello I am new to flutter and i want to do native function calls using flutter, i wrote an sample native code app and it is working as expected. Now i want to use some packages on my android code, which is platform specific.

I have added my dependcies in my `build.gradle` file and it the gradle build is success,

But i cannot use the package there,

**say for example**: i have added the dependency for the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2` and `gradle build` is success and now icannot access their methods and other stuffs. Please let me know to what to do with it. Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kixKb.png)

Comment: I think you need to add the dependencies inside your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hisam the dependencies for the flutter should be added there, but i wonder should android project dependencies should also be addded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked, i opened the android project as an new android project in android studio which resolved the issue.